# Combinatorics - Counting the ways to paint the unit squares of a $2 \times 3$ rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I've been doing more preparation for the upcoming AMC8 and AMC10 competitions, and I have found a few more questions that I would like to find efficient ways to do. The problem set goes a little something like this:

> How many ways are there to paint the unit squares in a $2 \times 3$ rectangle where each cell is a solid color

> (a) using $2$ colors when the rectangle cannot move?

> (b) using $4$ colors when the rectangle cannot move?

> (c) using $3$ colors when the rectangle can rotate?

> (d) using $3$ colors when the rectangle can rotate and flip over?

> (e) using $3$ colors when no two adjacent squares can have the same color and the rectangle cannot move?

> (f) using $3$ colors when no two adjacent squares can have the same color and the rectangle can rotate and flip over?

Now I have managed to solve a few of these so far. (a) and (b) were on the simpler side, as they would be $2^6$ and $4^6$ respectively, but I'm starting to have trouble when the rotation aspect comes into play in (c). I initially thought that maybe I could simply divide the total by $2$, since each rotation would cause one case to have another one that can be rotated to it. But then I realized certain cases that are symmetrical (for example, all 6 squares of one color) have no case for rotation. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Moving onto (e) where it adds the restriction that no two adjacent squares can have the same color, I've had a bit of some better luck. I've figured out that if I consider each column separately, I could simply multiply it at the end. And apparently, every other column expect the first column actually has the same amount of possibilities. So the first column is just $3 \cdot 2$. And working through all possible cases for the second column would get $3$ possibilities. Then I could do $6 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 54$. But does anyone know a better method of finding the total cases in the second column? I can imagine that if the amount of colors were to increase, it would get quite difficult to manually list out and work out like I did. And once again for (f), I'm having the same issue where I'm not sure what to do to eliminate the extra rotation and reflection scenarios. Can anyone help out here?

Comment: Asking multiple questions in 1 query is frowned upon.
For part (c), I think that you are skipping a step.  This sort
of problem requires that you stretch your intuition, through
visualization.  Why not experiment visually, creating your own
2x3 rectangle, trying out various patterns, and see which patterns
are affected re the rectangle can rotate.  For example, what
happens if you put 1 color in the upper left corner, and all of
the rest of the rectangle is another color.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Here though, I'm primarily just asking how to deal with the rotations/flips that can happen though, even though there's multiple questions involved. And I'll take a look into what you're saying and see if I can find anything.